# Custom Control Background Color in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, custom-controls

I have created a custom control as you see below (Generic.xaml):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCC}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCC}">
                <Grid Name="grd" Height="{Binding Height}" Width="{Binding Width}">
                    <Rectangle Name="FirstRec" Fill="Blue"/>
                    <Rectangle Name="SecondRec" Fill="Black" Margin="1"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property = "IsMouseOver" Value = "True">
            <Setter Property = "Background" Value = "Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

For *FirstRec* I want to get the Foreground color of the CC (instead of blue) and for the *SecondRec* I need to get the Background (instead of black). Therefore now the trigger does not work properly! I also don't want to bind the Height and Width of the Grid because the CC has its own height and width but I don't know how to use it! Would you please help me?!

EDIT:

It is actually a switch that has a status. if status == 0 it shows an empty rectangle. if status == 1 it shows a filled rectangle. if status == 3 || status == 4 it shows a red cross on it. here is the cc:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:BreakerCC}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:BreakerCC}">
                <Grid Name="grd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" >
                    <Rectangle Name="MainRectangle" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                    <Path Name="Line1" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1" Stretch="Fill">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1" />
                        </Path.Data>
                        <Path.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Path">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="0x00">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="0x01">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="0x02">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="0x03">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Path.Style>
                    </Path>
                    <Path Name="Line2" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1" Stretch="Fill">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="1,0" />
                        </Path.Data>
                        <Path.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Path">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="0x00">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="0x01">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="0x02">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="0x03">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Path.Style>
                    </Path>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And this is the definition in MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="230KV" TargetType="Control">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="132KV" TargetType="Control">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="400KV" TargetType="Control">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Purple"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <CC:BreakerCC Status="{Binding Status}" Style="{StaticResource 132KV}" Height="20" Width="20"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

But when the status is 3 or 4 i need to change the Foreground to Red and that doesn't work!

Comment: Hi @RaminRabbani and welcome to stackoverflow. Do you have an error message you can post or could you provide some details on what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TemplateBindings for the Brushes. Binding Width and Height is not at all necessary.

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyCC">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyCC">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                    <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

As a note, instead of a Grid you would usually have a Border element and assign TemplateBindings to its Background, BorderBrush and BorderThickness properties - as done by default by Visual Studio when you create a new custom control.

---

EDIT: It seems that you do not need a custom control at all. Just create ContentControl styles like these:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="BaseStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Path x:Name="path" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                              Data="{TemplateBinding Content}" Stretch="Fill"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="0">
                            <Setter TargetName="path"
                                    Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="1">
                            <Setter TargetName="path"
                                    Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding Foreground,
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="230KV" TargetType="ContentControl" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="132KV" TargetType="ContentControl" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="400KV" TargetType="ContentControl" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Purple"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource 230KV}">
        <PathGeometry>M0,0 L1,1 M0,1 L1,0</PathGeometry>
    </ContentControl>
    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource 132KV}">
        <PathGeometry>M0,0 L1,1 M0,1 L1,0</PathGeometry>
    </ContentControl>
    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource 400KV}">
        <PathGeometry>M0,0 L1,1 M0,1 L1,0</PathGeometry>
    </ContentControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I could not add two Rectangles to a border and this was why I changed it to Grid.

Comment: You don't actually need two Rectangle for this. A Border element has a Background and a BorderBrush, which result in the same visual appearance with BorderThickness set to 1.

Comment: Can you please also help me for the trigger? I changed 'Background' to 'Foreground' and it does not work. if I change the Height or Width it works properly but I don't know why I can't change the foreground!

Comment: You've probably set Foreground explicitly when you instantiate the control. Replace that by a Style Setter. You might also explain what you are finally trying to achieve. Is it just a rectangle with a fill and border color, or is there more than that?

Comment: Ok I post it here! Thanks.

Comment: It is also unclear what the purpose of the control's Status property is. The DataTriggers are operating on the Status property of the view model (i.e. the binding source) but not on the control's Status property. If there isn't any additional behavior associated with the Status property, it is redundant. And if there is no other property, you wouldn't even need a custom control. See the edited answer.

Comment: Sorry for sending it as an answer. I didn't know the rules. Yes you're right. I actually don't need Status!! I can bind triggers to viewmodel! But as you saw my view it's consisted of 3 or 4 other shapes and the final view has about 500 objects like this on one page. Isn't it the best way of implementing?! would you please tell me which method is the best?

Comment: Note that you can still edit your question, and delete your answer. That said, you may use ContentControls like shown in the edited answer.